# Preserving model state with Post/Redirect/Get pattern and URL rewriting

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mod-rewrite, post-redirect-get

First of all, I know that there are similar questions regarding "Preserving model state with Post/Redirect/Get pattern", but none of these have my very specific problem:

**background**:

My Code is working in an enterprise CMS software which does a lot of things. One of them is URL rewriting: Whenever I generate Links to my controller, dependending on the environment, the links are shortened - That's a SEO thing and can't be discussed.

I.e. if my Controller URL is `/webapp/servlet/myController/doSomething`, the generated URL will be `/myController/doSomething`. There's some LinkProcessing functionality that we have to use.

An apache rewrite rule will then expand this short url to `/webapp/servlet/myController/doSomething` when the apache uses `mod_rewrite` to call the corresponsing code on the tomcat:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myController/(.*)
RewriteRule ^/myController/(.*) /webapp/servlet/myController/$1 [PT,L]
```

**Problem**:

I'm trying to implement the Post/Redirect/Get pattern using Spring 3.1.2. I'm generating a form and POST it to the Controller, which validated and makes a redirect to either the success or error page using GET (*Post/Redirect/Get pattern*).

(highly simplified) **Code**:

```
@RequestMapping()
public class MyController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/doDispatch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public RedirectView handleDispatch(RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                                     @Validated @ModelAttribute FormBean formBean,
                                     BindingResult binding) {
    if (binding.hasErrors()) {
      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(formBean);
      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX+"formBean", binding);

      return new RedirectView(generateLink("/error"));
    } else {
      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(formBean);
      redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX+"formBean", binding);
      return new RedirectView(generateLink("/success"));

    }
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/success")
  public ModelAndView handleSuccess(@ModelAttribute FormBean formBean) {
    // do stuff (save things in the DB)
    // ...

    final ModelAndView modelAndView = createModelAndView(formBean);
    modelAndView.addObject("success", true);
    return modelAndView;
  }
  @RequestMapping(value = "/error")
  public ModelAndView handleError(@Validated @ModelAttribute FormBean formBean,
                                  BindingResult binding) {
    final ModelAndView modelAndView = createModelAndView(formBean);
    modelAndView.addObject("binding", binding);
    modelAndView.addObject("formBean", formBean);
    return modelAndView;
  }
}
```

The problem ist that this generateLink() method will either generate links starting with `/webapp/servlet` or not - depending on the environment/success. And that's how this whole Enterprice CMS thing works. (that's the part which cannot be discussed)

Spring Flash-Attributes on the other hand work hand in hand with the URLs that are returned and store the URL as part of the FlashMap:

Quote from http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes :

> To reduce the possibility of such issues, `RedirectView` automatically "stamps" `FlashMap` instances with the path and query parameters of the target redirect URL. In turn the default `FlashMapManager` matches that information to incoming requests when looking up the "input" `FlashMap`.

Since the next request (let's say I've had an error and returned "/myController/error") will be expanded to `/webapp/servlet/myController/error`,  the FlashMap will not apply to this request, **since the URLs do not match**.

The code that is responsible is this here (`AbstractFlashMapManager.java:157` ff):

```
  protected boolean isFlashMapForRequest(FlashMap flashMap, HttpServletRequest request) {

    if (flashMap.getTargetRequestPath() != null) {
      String requestUri = this.urlPathHelper.getOriginatingRequestUri(request);
      if (!requestUri.equals(flashMap.getTargetRequestPath())
          && !requestUri.equals(flashMap.getTargetRequestPath() + "/")) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    // ...
  }
```

**Question**:

Do you know a way how I can still generate short URLs on the one hand, but pass the FlashAttributes to the following GET request?

Best regards and thanks for your help in advance,
Alexander

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found so far is using an `Interceptor` that updates the `targetRequestPath` by prefixing `/<webappPath>/<servletPath>` to those FlashMaps from `RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(request)` that are missing this information. *BTW*: this can only be done in the `afterCompletion` method, because otherwise the `targetRequestPath` won't be set at all, when using a `RedirectView`.

Any other, better solutions?